# Can we enable a forum like feature in salesforce communities?

Tags: community

Can we enable a forum like feature in salesforce communities ?

So that anonymous users can have discussions without login..
Similar to this StackExchange, anonymous visitors should be able to post their questions, and discuss on topics...

Comment: What do you mean by "anonymous users"?  In your example, StackExchange still requires a user identity in order to participate.  For Salesforce, have you looked at the Chatter External license?  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_chatter.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

Force.com sites may be a better option for this usecase but for the ability to comment you might need licenses